# "No such customer" error when creating a stripe session with a user who has an email

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Here's the relevant code. I'm using Django, with [stripe-python](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python) (2.46.0) along with [dj-stripe](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe) (2.3.0).

```
import stripe
from djstripe.models import Customer

customer, created = Customer.get_or_create(subscriber=my_django_user)
stripe_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    customer=customer,
    ...
)
```

When the `my_django_user.email` field is empty, this works just fine and the `stripe_session` is created successfully. But if the email is set, the session creation fails with "No such customer":

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_bla: No such customer: <my_django_user's email>
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think this is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158598/no-such-customer-when-charging-with-stripe) because `Customer.get_or_create` makes an API request to stripe and so does `stripe.checkout.Session.create`, and IIUC both requests are handled under the same account. (Also the above code works with a brand new user, as long as the email's empty.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `customer` field is supposed to be an ID on an existing customer in Stripe. You're passing in a Customer model instance into that field in your code.

You should probably pass in `customer.email` into the `customer_email` field as:

```
stripe_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    customer_email=customer.email,
    ...
)
```

Have a read through the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create).

Comment: You're exactly right, thanks so much @Wiggy A.! Works perfectly when I pass in the id instead. Seems so obvious in hindsight because stripe itself doesn't know about Django models. I guess I've been spoiled by Django's db-querying syntax XD